# Update firewall rules to allow printing when firewall is turned on

Tags: networking, printing, firewall

[This page in the Ubuntu help wiki](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/NetworkPrintingWithUbuntu) describes how to use the command as follows to update the firewall to allow something through:

```
iptables -A INPUT -p tcp --dport 631 -j ACCEPT
```

To apply this rule after each start/restart of the system, use `/etc/rc.local`.

Does this mean edit the `/etc/rc.local file`? How do I do that?

Comment: I would strongly recommend you use Ubuntu Firewall (ufw) instead of iptables. This would involve first enabling Ubuntu Firewall (`sudo ufw enable`) and then allow TCP port 631: `sudo ufw allow 631/tcp`. This will create the iptables rules for you, and the rule will persist throughout reboots. You can view rules with: `sudo ufw status`. If you want to remove the rule: `sudo ufw delete allow 631/tcp`, and if you want to disable Ubuntu Firewall: `sudo ufw disable`. I just find ufw much easier to use (it's much more user-friendly).

Answer (score 1):

All I needed was

```
sudo ufw allow 631/tcp
```

instead of

```
iptables -A INPUT -p tcp --dport 631 -j ACCEPT
```

I am now able to print with the firewalls turned on at last.

Answer (score 1):

Ubuntu uses CUPS for print services. With modern equipment CUPS typically uses IPP to communicate with the printer using port 631.

**Option 1**: Scott is correct about the command line ufw usage

```
sudo ufw allow 631/tcp
```

**Option 2**: Install Gufw which is the GUI for ufw. Add a firewall rule in Gufw to allow network printing.

```
sudo apt install gufw
```

Since many users will not know the ports they need to open for an application or service, using Gufw is helpful because it already has the ports categorized and searchable by name or topic.

For example, adding a rule using the Gufw Preconfigured tab lets the user type in a filter term like "print" and CUPS is automatically displayed. The filter UX is not perfect, but it's an added cheat sheet for beginners.

I don't have enough reputation points to post an image, so here's a link to a screen grab I took of the Gufw dialog box equivalent of the command line. [Image of Gufw Rule Dialog](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bNHnv.png)

Enabling and disabling the firewall is clicking a button or two in the application. Users can read the official help documentation for any general use questions: [Gufw-Community Help Wiki](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Gufw)

Answer (score 0):

The file `/etc/rc.local` gets executed at the end of every multiuser runlevel, so it will run during start of the system. You can edit you `rc.local` file using a text editor (you will require super user permissions for this) and add the iptables rule (above the line `exit 0`).

If you use vim, for example, then you could do

```
sudo vim /etc/rc.local
```